# PHPExcel How to set the cell name?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Normally in excel you can give a specific name to the cells.  How can this be done in phpexcel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 4.6.38 of the Developer documentation describes how to do this: the section entitled "Define a named range"

```
$objPHPExcel->addNamedRange(
    new PHPExcel_NamedRange('PersonFN', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(), 'B1') 
);
```

Comment: thanks, I checked all developer doc for something line setCellName but let see if this works. I know about this NameRange. thank you again

Comment: Just another question, I am looking also for getting name of range of a cell, but the method suggest in documentation seems not to work:$alfanum_coor=$cell->getCoordinate();

                $range_name=$objPHPExcel->getNamedRange($alfanum_coor,$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());. Any suggestion?